# Workflow Triggering for any update

Tags: workflow, email, workflow-variable

My below workflow is designed to send email notifications only when a specific field in my list is updated, however I'm currently receiving email when any list item is updated. Even though the two fields below contain exactly the same values.

Both Additional Question Holder and Addtitonal Question are text fields that allow multiple lines and this is a 2010 workflow, I could create a 2013 version if that would resolve the issue.

Can anyone see an issue with my logic?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Quinn to my understanding this is happening in your case:

The first time when these lines will get executed (for both the fields not being equal), the mail will be sent. 
I am assuming your workflow gets executes on every edit/update item for the list.

Now the next time whenever an item gets updated, the workflow executes and again it starts mailing because both those fields are still different.

Therefore no matter how many times any item is updated for any field , the emails will be sent there onward.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a 2010 workflow, you ought to be able to use the `Wait for field to change` action. Once the field changes, send your emails, and that's it.

Comment: I've tried this but if I update a different field in my list the workflow fires again and I receive the same email, is there a way to only send an email when a specific field changes?

Comment: Any action after this will only send once the field has changed. The workflow will fire again, but will pause until this field changes.